# If $S_n$ is non-decreasing then $S_m \lt S_n$ whenever $m \lt n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am stuck on how to go about proving this: So I will list some of the facts of what I know at this point and maybe someone could push me in the right direction.

Since $S_n$ is non-decreasing that means $S_n \le S_{n+1}$ I know that if it's non-decreasing means it's monotonic. But this is where I don't really know what to do with this information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand exactly your question. But if $m>n$ and $(S_n)$ non-decreasing then we have that $$S_n\leq S_{n+1}\leq S_{n+2}\leq ...\leq S_m$$
and thus $S_{n}\leq S_m$, and you can't say better ! (i.e. it's not a strict inequality).

Comment: The original question is what was asked and it does't make sense to me, I was wondering if there is any possible way to prove what its asking.

Comment: The question definitely should be "If $(S_n)$ non-decreasing, prove that $S_n\leq S_m$ whenever $m>n$."

Comment: Your absolutely sure? This would not be the first time my professor goofed up when writing our a question!

Comment: Yes I am. For exemple, if $S_n=1$ for all $n$, then $(S_n)$ is a non decreasing sequence, and for all $m,n$, $S_m=S_n$.

Comment: Yeah I completely understand! Thank You so much!